# Jquery addClass fadeIn fadeOut not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fadein, fadeout, addclass

I am modifying bootstrap carousel support for IE8. This works in chrome and FF but not IE 8, it will change with no fade in. Does anyone know why?

```
<style>
  .carousel .activerow {display: none;} 
  .carousel .row { left: 0; opacity: 1; }
  </style>

  /*I have many rows of data in the dom
   They are not visible until'active' class 
   is added.

   This code is binded to a link
  */
  var activeset = $active; //contains the contents of current row
  var nextset = $next;    //contains contents of the next 

  $active.fadeOut('slow', function () {            
      activeset.removeClass('activerow');
      nextset.addClass('active');
      nextset.fadeIn('slow');          

    });
```

Comment: Anything showing up in your console?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a type-o.

```
$active.fadeOut(....
```

may need to be

```
$(active).fadeOut(....
```

Edit: Didn't think before I posted this.

Since you're caching the element are you sure your selector is returning a match?

Comment: tried it but made no differnce. That would just create jquery dom object right?

Comment: Well, if you're referencing $active you've had to have cached it somewhere with var active = $(selectors). Are you sure that selector is returning elements?

Comment: I think IE8 does not support CSS opacity. That is the reason why it does't work